# Writing xlsx with Apache SXSSF, can't read with XSSF

Tags: java, excel

I have an application (Java) that takes in an xlsx file from an outside source, reads it with XSSF, and then spits out certain rows of that file based on some criteria and writes those rows to a new file generated via SXSSF.  Those new files that are generated also get sent through the application to be read.  The problem I'm having is that the XSSF parser is not seeing the contents of the new spreadsheets that are generated via SXSSF.  If I open the file it looks fine - the data is there, and if I simply save it and then run it through the process again, XSSF will read it.  I'm guessing maybe there's some type of file property that SXSSF isn't setting when it writes the file, which would prevent the parser from reading the spreadsheet?  Any idea what could be causing this?

Here's the code:

```
private SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();    

public void writeFile(String outputFile, ArrayList<List<? extends Object>> rows) throws IOException {
    Sheet sh = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
    int numRows = rows.size();
    for (int i = 0; i <= numRows; i++) {
        Row row = sh.createRow(i);
        for (int cellNum = 0; cellNum <= rows.get(i).size(); cellNum++) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum);
            if (rows.get(i).get(cellNum) == null) {
                cell.setCellValue("");
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(rows.get(i).get(cellNum).toString());
            }
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        wb.write(out);
        wb.dispose();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you called dispose method on SXSSF workbook on completion? Did you  close output stream?

Comment: @Miljenko Yea I'm calling both.  I'll post the code.

Comment: This looks OK, I have similar setup but did not have any problems (probably because I do not read again my generated Excel).

Comment: Yea same here, everything seems to work fine until it has to re-read a file that was written by the writer.